# Set Content Compose Dialog Works on Phone, but Not Tablet? - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-jetpack-compose

I've run this through the debugger a hundred times and stepped into the `setContent` over and over. I can't figure out why.  No errors given.

Works perfectly on Android phone.

When on a tablet, the entire `setContent` code block is skipped over.

This is the piece of the fragment that deals with opening the dialog.  Any ideas?

```
    (activity as? MapActivity)?.findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.map_fragment_container_composeview)
        ?.setContent {
            // Delegate to observe the showDialog state in viewModel
            val showDialogState: Boolean by dialog.showDialog.collectAsState()

            MdcTheme {
                OptionSelectComposeDialog(
                    show = showDialogState,
                    onDismiss = dialog::onDialogDismiss,
                    onConfirm = dialog::onDialogConfirm,
                    vm = dialog,
                )
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's not likely. You should check to see if you haven't created a different layout for tablets using Studio Templates or something of sorts.

Comment: You have a lot of question marks there. Are one of those returning null? That's what you should be debugging. Note that a fragment should never be reaching up UI it doesn't control (i.e., your activity's UI) - that's why there are [other ways to communicate between a fragment and activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate).

Comment: @ianhanniballake That was it! I took the ?s out to force it to crash and it did! Thank you!

Comment: Oh questions that get resolved with a comment or two are TIGHT!!!

Comment: Yes. Just to further document for anyone else who comes across, we use a `layout` folder with the default (phone) layout. There was a separate folder `layout-sw600dp` that is used for tablets. I got this confused because the files in both folders have the same names, but the `composeview` needed to be added to both layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying from comments to show the resolution (thanks to @ianhanniballake
and @MARSK)

Just to further document for anyone else who comes across, we use a layout folder with the default (phone) layout. There was a separate folder layout-sw600dp that is used for tablets. I got this confused because the files in both folders have the same names, but the composeview needed to be added to both layouts.

Once the `composeview` was added to the `layout-sw600dp` folder, the issue went away.  <s>I also removed many of the nullable (?) markers.  Those markers were preventing any errors from appearing.</s>

Update:
Added the nullable `?` markers back in. I'm told it's a good way to future-proof your code.

Comment: Just so you know, you definitely should place the null safety symbols in your code. You removed them but that was only to find the issue, afaik. You don't have to ditch them they are there to be used.

Comment: @MARSK Good call. I ended up adding them back.

Comment: Oh immediately acting on strangers' advice is TIGHT! Wait that didn't sound right

Comment: @MARSK lol. I did ask my senior about it and he agreed with you.

Comment: Immediately acting on strangers' advice? He agreed you should do that? Sir I don't know what your senior is telling you but I think you need to contact HR.